# Javascript - Local object variable not conserved between promise and await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, web-worker

I am using the code below which higlights the fact that local object variable (`HitCurrent`) is not conserved between the core of `computeHit(HitCurrent,'computer')` and after the calling of this function in the following way : `await computeHit(HitCurrent, 'computer');`

In the core of `computeHit(HitCurrent,'computer')`, array `HitCurrent.arrayCurrent` is modified (actually, it computes the hit for computer) : But the issue is that modifications are not conserved once I come back to the main thread (after `await computeHit(HitCurrent, 'computer')`.

If I do, after the `await`, a `console.log` of an array contained in this local object variable, I don't get the same array than one which is right computed into core of `computeHit` function. I don't understand this behavior.

```
// Perform hit computer
(async () => {
// Wait computeHit function
await computeHit(HitCurrent, 'computer');

// Output array which is not the same than into computeHit 
console.log('into async : HitCurrent.arrayCurrent', HitCurrent.arrayCurrent);
alert('into async() function');
})();
```

}

with `computerHit` function like :

```
function computeHit(HitCurrent, mode) {

if (mode == 'computer') {

return new Promise( resolve => {
// Creation of webworker
let firstWorker = new Worker(workerScript);
firstWorker.onmessage = function (event) {
  resolve(event.data);
}
// Post current copy of HitCurrent, i.e HitCurrent
firstWorker.postMessage([HitCurrent, HitCurrent.playerCurrent, maxNodes]);
}).then(({result}) => {

// Get back game board of webworker
HitCurrent = result.HitResult;

// Get back suggested hit computed by webworker
[a,b] = HitCurrent.coordPlayable;

// Drawing all lines from suggested hit (in 8 directions)
// HitCurrent.arrayCurrent is modified HERE !
for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
   exploreHitLine(HitCurrent, a, b, k, 'drawing');
}

// Remove playable hits
cleanHits('playable', HitCurrent);

// Display current game
displayCurrentHit(HitCurrent);

// Output array which is good
alert('into computeHit function');
console.log('into promise - HitCurrent.arrayCurrent', HitCurrent.arrayCurrent);
})
}
}
```

I expect to get back the same array (i.e `HitCurrent.arrayCurrent`) between the computation of it into `computeHit` function and after the `await` call, but this is not the case.

How could I fix this issue ? I tried to pass by global variables, without success. Feel free to ask me further informations if you need it.

Comment: When asking for help, please be sure to format and indent your code in a consistent, readable way. (It's useful when *not* asking for help, too.) I tried to do it for you, but your second code block has a syntax error (and extra `}`), and so my guess at the correct format might have been incorrect.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder . What's the shortcut for good indentation ? I only know CTRL+K

Comment: You format the code correctly yourself, and then select all of it, and press Ctrl+K which will indent it a further four spaces (to mark it up as code). Ctrl+K doesn't correct your indentation, it just adds the initial four spaces. So for instance in your first code block, you don't have any indentation starting on the second line, but the second line should be indented because it's within the async arrow function.

Comment: "*I get an error*" - **what** error do you get?

Comment: @Bergi. I put it in my **UPDATE** with a screenshot. Why can't I do a hardcopy, that would make the things simpler, right ?

Comment: @Bergi . have you got a solution to my issue ?, maybe I could set a parameter to `async()` by setting `async (HitCurrent)  => {` ?

Comment: @youpilat13 I think that error has nothing to do with asynchrony or `computeHit`. Use the debugger to look at the values and check whether they are like what you expect. If the data is wrong, it probably comes wrong from your web worker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rewrite your code **just** a little and rename some variables.
Literally, I've renamed the parameters of `computeHit(..)` to `my_variable_1` and `my_variable_2`.
You may want to check/admit this does not change the code execution.

You should now understand why the `HitCurrent` in your async code block is never modified. Refer to simplified code block 3, which *will* yield 42. Hope it helps.

Code block 1 unchanged :

```
// Perform hit computer
(async () => {
// Wait computeHit function
await computeHit(HitCurrent, 'computer');

// Output array which is not the same than into computeHit 
console.log('into async : HitCurrent.arrayCurrent', HitCurrent.arrayCurrent);
alert('into async() function');
})();
```

Code block 2 with renamed variables :

```
function computeHit(my_variable_1, my_variable_2) {

if (my_variable_2 == 'computer') {

return new Promise( resolve => {
// Creation of webworker
let firstWorker = new Worker(workerScript);
firstWorker.onmessage = function (event) {
  resolve(event.data);
}
// Post current copy of my_variable_1, i.e my_variable_1
firstWorker.postMessage([my_variable_1, my_variable_1.playerCurrent, maxNodes]);
}).then(({result}) => {

// Get back game board of webworker
my_variable_1 = result.HitResult;

// Get back suggested hit computed by webworker
[a,b] = my_variable_1.coordPlayable;

// Drawing all lines from suggested hit (in 8 directions)
// my_variable_1.arrayCurrent is modified HERE !
for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
   exploreHitLine(my_variable_1, a, b, k, 'drawing');
}

// Remove playable hits
cleanHits('playable', my_variable_1);

// Display current game
displayCurrentHit(my_variable_1);

// Output array which is good
alert('into computeHit function');
console.log('into promise - my_variable_1.arrayCurrent', my_variable_1.arrayCurrent);
})
}
}
```

Code block 3, simplified :

```
// Perform hit computer
var magicNumber = 42;
(async () => {
    await computeHit(magicNumber, 'computer');
    console.log('magic is ', magicNumber);
})();

function computeHit(my_variable_1, my_variable_2) {
    if (my_variable_2 == 'computer') {
        // Get back game board of webworker
        my_variable_1 = 314159;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assigning to a parameter within a function has no effect whatsoever on any variable used as the argument for that parameter in the call. Simplifying your code:

```js
function computeHit(HitCurrent) {
    HitCurrent = "something else";
}
let HitCurrent = "something";
computeHit(HitCurrent);
console.log(HitCurrent); // "something", not "something else"
```

There is no link whatsoever between the `HitCurrent` variable in `computeHit(HitCurrent)` and the `HitCurrent` parameter inside the call to `computeHit`, other than that the value of the first was read and passed into the function as the value of the second.

If you want to update `HitCurrent` based on what happens in `computeHit`, either:

1. Return the new `HitCurrent` and assign it back to the variable: `HitCurrent = computeHit(...`
2. Make `HitCurrent` refer to an object, and modify the object's state (e.g., use properties on it).

Comment: Crowder. I forgot to say that HitCurrent is an object, so I can modify its attributes when I put it in argument of a function, can't I ?

Comment: @youpilat13 - Yes, you can (that's #2 above), but that's not what `computeHit` does (at least, as far as I can tell with the unindented code). It does `HitCurrent = result.HitResult;`, which is replacing the value in the `HitCurrent` parameter, not modifying the object the `HitCurrent` parameter refers to.

Comment: @T.JCrowder . In my **UPDATE**, I tried several things : 1) using a temporary variable `HitTemp` and doing a reference copy with `HitCurrent`. 2) making a hard copy of `arrayCurrent` with this temporary variable. In both cases, I get an error of `undefined`type error (you can see screenshot). Could you explain me how to keep after `away computeHit` the modified `arrayCurrent` ? thanks